# Error with whitespaces when trying to tokenize text in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a data frame with 2 columns. The first column (content_cleaned) contains rows holding sentences. The second column (meaningful) contains an associated binary label.

The issue I am having is with whitespaces when I am trying to tokenize the text in the content_cleaned column. Here is my code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathname, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df[['content_cleaned', 'meaningful']]
df = df.sample(frac=1)

#Transposed columns into numpy arrays 
X = np.asarray(df[['content_cleaned']])
y = np.asarray(df[['meaningful']])

#Split into training and testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21) 

# Create tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100) #No row has more than 100 words.

#Tokenize the predictors (text)
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_train.astype(np.int32), mode="binary")
X_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_test.astype(np.int32), mode="binary")

#Convert the labels to the binary
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(y_train) 
y_train = encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test)
```

The line of code the error highlights is:

```
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_train.astype(np.int32), mode="binary")
```

The error message is:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: "STX's better than reported quarter is likely to bode well for WDC results."
```

The sentence after "base 10:" is an example of one of the rows in the column containing the text. That would be an example sentence I am trying to tokenize.

I was led to believe that this is an issue with NumPy, but I am also convinced this could be an error in my method to tokenize this text array.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not tokenizing the text, the `sequences_to_matrix` method not tokenizes texts but converts list of sequences to [matrices](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/sequences_to_matrix.html). There are lots of way to tokenize text data, so if you want to use the keras Tokenizer you can follow this way:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

# Tip for you: the num_words param is not the max length of given sentences
# It is the maximum number of words to keep in dictionary
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100)

# Creates a word index dictionary in itself
# Do not fit on your test data it will mislead on your score
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)

# Now you can convert the texts to sequences
X_train_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

# You need to add pads to sentences to fix them to same size
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
max_len = 100
X_train = pad_sequences(X_train_encoded, maxlen=max_len)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test_encoded, maxlen=max_len)
```

Hope it will help you, check out [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-deep-learning-keras/) there is a great tutorial about preprocessing text with keras.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me! When trying to run your code, it is highlighting: "tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)" with error: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'".

Comment: Also, once all the padding is done and the LabelBinarizer is done for the target variable, I can then create my layers and fit my model?

Comment: Do not cast pandas series to numpy array, you can pass directly to keras tokenizer or convert them to list. You can create the model after padding. I think you need to follow a nlp tutorial such as sentiment analysis with keras, most nlp use cases includes same preprocessing steps.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick thank you! Before closing the question, I do have one final question. After the preprocessing steps you provided, can the data we preprocessed be fed into the network?

Comment: Yes you can fed into the network but while constructing the model make sure your input layer shape same with input length (in this case max length of sentence).